# ggplot2: Colour variable independent from others

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I ignore the colour by value for one of the variables? 
(ie: I would like variable C to be ploted in size as scaled value like it is, but ignore the colouring by value and have an independent colour (black))

```
data <- tibble::tibble(
  value = c(4.07, 5.76, 2.87,4.94,5.48, 6.75,1.53,1.35, 1.32), 
  Variable = rep(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3), rep("C",3))),
  Experiment = rep(c(1:3),3))

data <- data %>%group_by(Variable)%>%
  mutate(scaled_val = scale(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

data$Variable <- factor(data$Variable,levels=rev(unique(data$Variable)))

ggplot(data, aes(x = Experiment, y = Variable, label=NA)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = scaled_val, colour = value)) + 
  geom_text(hjust = 1, size = 2) +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(1,0))+
  coord_fixed(ratio=4)
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, what is it your desired output?

Comment: Ignore the ``geom_point(aes(..., colour = value)`` for variable C and colour it manually as "black"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you should be able to subset the data in `geom_point` and overlay two `geom_point` geoms:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Experiment, y = Variable, label=NA)) +
  geom_point(data=subset(data, Variable %in% c("A","B")), aes(size = scaled_val, colour = value)) + 
  geom_point(data=subset(data, Variable=="C"), aes(size = scaled_val)) + 
  geom_text(hjust = 1, size = 2) +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "darkblue")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(1,0))+
  coord_fixed(ratio=4)
```

[image]